# Add Prefix to Reverse Routes

Tags: scala, playframework, routes

I am looking for a way to add a prefix to all reverse routes of an html template without wrapping them all in function applications. I planned to use an html base tag but the reverse routes all start with a slash and therefore are relative to the host of the base tag rather than the full URL. Is there any feature I might be missing for a more robust solution?

Comment: I not tested with all browsers - but you can use relative paths: `page.html` `../page.html` - then browser will recalculate the url depends on `<base href..`

Comment: Second solution: handle request in your GlobalSettings `override def onHandlerNotFound(request: RequestHeader)` (context should not exist) or in `onRouteRequest(request: RequestHeader): Option[Handler]` and redirect - handle the request to proper path. Redirect is heavy - needs new http request. But works. For example you define `GET /index.html cont.method` - you receive `/context/index.html` . So you can cut `/context` and redirect to `/index.html` `Future( Results.Redirect(new Call(request.method, "/index.html")))`

Comment: I am currently using an approach like this. Now I would like to change the reverse routes for these requests. That is, all reverse routes of a redirected request should use the context.

Answer (score 3):

- rename `routes` to `context.routes`
- create empty `routes` file
- add to `routes` the line:

  `->           /context         context.Routes`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I forgot to mention that I am looking for a solution that allows me to dynamically change the prefix as I'd like to serve the same content with different contexts.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish something like this, to facilitate communication to my app of my app's own URLs in a DRY way, to propagate query parameters debug settings used in development through internal links, and also because I find Play's reverse router to be super ugly, I created a URL abstraction I like a lot better. It works like this:

1) I created a type to represent URLs symbolically:

```
/** Represents a URL that can possibly be a webpage */
sealed trait PageUrl

case class SectionUrl(slug: String) extends PageUrl
case class StaticPageUrl(slug: String) extends PageUrl
case class ExternalUrl(url: String) extends PageUrl
```

2) I created a class for resolving these objects into full URLs:

```
/** Wrapper to propagate request override flags to internal links */
case class UrlWrapper(params: Seq[(String, String)]) {
  def apply(url: PageUrl, additionalParams: Seq[(String, String)] = Seq.empty): String = {
    url match {
      case SectionUrl(slug) => urlAndParams(routes.PageRendererController.showSectionPage(slug).url)
      case StaticPageUrl(slug) => urlAndParams(routes.PageRendererController.showStaticPage(slug).url)
      case ExternalUrl(u) => u
    }
  }

  def urlAndParams(url: String, additionalParams: Seq[(String, String)] = Seq.empty): String = {
    def urlEncode = (u: String) => java.net.URLEncoder.encode(u, "UTF-8")
    val formattedParams = (queryParams ++ additionalParams).map{ case (key, value) => s"$key=${urlEncode(value)}" }.mkString("&")
    val paramOption = if (formattedParams.nonEmpty) Some(formattedParams) else None
    (Seq(url) ++ paramOption).mkString(if (url.indexOf("?") > 0) "&" else "?")
  }
}
```

You could easily modify this to provide a prefix always by default, or upon request via some other method.

3) In a trait/class that all my views extend, I declare an implicit field of type `UrlWrapper`, that will be available to my templates, so I can do:

```
@(option1: String, urlParam: PageUrl)(implicit url: UrlWrapper)

...

<a href="@url(urlParam)">My link</a>

...
```

As a bonus, since my pages all correspond to models in my app, I added to `UrlWrapper` additional methods for converting model objects to resolved URLs:

```
case class UrlWrapper(...) {
  ...

  def forSection(section: Section, additionalParams: Seq[(String, String)] = Seq.empty): String = {
    apply(SectionUrl(section.slug), additionalParams)
  }

  def forStaticPage(staticPage: StaticPage, additionalParams: Seq[(String, String)] = Seq.empty): String = {
    apply(StaticPageUrl(staticPage.slug), additionalParams)
  }
}
```

Comment: I would have hoped for a less invasive solution as this approach still requires me to wrap all my reverse routes. Furthermore it is quite error prone as you might simply forget the application of `url`.

Comment: @JanChristiansen, I guess you could forget to call `url`, but that would be like forgetting to call `routes.MyController.showPage(...).url`. It's just far less verbose. You are right that it's a decent amount of work upfront. But in a big project with a high ratio of URL usages to routes (as it is in my app), I believe it very nicely factors the cruft out of the controller and view code.